# lightgallery library + lg-thumbnail plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightgallery

I'm trying to setup lightgallery with lg-thumbnail plugin in a WordPress installation.

https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html

https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#lg-thumbnial

Lightgallery alone seems to work without problems (so, HTML markup and enqueued script is OK) with this JS init:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#gallery-1").lightGallery();
    });
```

So, my next step is to include lg-thumbnail plugin. After enqueue plugin JS I add `thumbnail:true`:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#gallery-1").lightGallery({
          thumbnail:true
        });
    });
```

But nothing happens. There is no errors in the console. Seems like there is no lg-thumbnail plugin present at all.

But, script is in its place:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
How can I diagnose the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that, everything works fine, including thumbnail plugin. I was worng with what was the plugin function. I thought that this plugin acts on the thumbnails before lightbox was launched, but actually insert thumbnails in the lightbox after it is launched.

My apologies.

Comment: I have the same issue but I don't understand what you did to fix it. Please explain

Comment: What did you dod to incude Thumbanil plugin, besides adding lg-thumbnail.js file?

Comment: This post is old. The LightGallery version changed and, as I said in the answer, there is no problem at all with the plugin. It worked. Please, post a new question with your details to looking for help.